# redmine bundler error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, redmine

I am setting up redmine with turnkey redmine appliance 12.0. I got following error after

executing command `bundle install -v 1.0.0`

```
root@redmine www/redmine# bundle update 
The source :rubygems is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure.
Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' if not.
The source :rubygems is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure.
Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' if not.
Updating git://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper.git
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.0) ruby depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.3.4)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

Comment: So the answer is in your last line... You need to update bundler by typing: gem install bundler